# macro initialization not clear

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel

I am not clear with following code

```
struct nsproxy init_nsproxy = INIT_NSPROXY(init_nsproxy);
```

this can be seen here 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/nsproxy.c?v=2.6.28#L27

I am not able to understand the use of macro INIT_NSPROXY which is here 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init_task.h?v=2.6.28#L53

the macro is defined to use INIT_NSPROXY(nsproxy) but when the above snippet is initializing then it is using INIT_NSPROXY(init_nsproxy) how is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define INIT_NSPROXY(nsproxy) // etc.
```

In this macro definition, `nsproxy` is the name of the parameter to the macro.

In the macro replacement list (everything on the line after the `#define INIT_NSPROXY(nsproxy)` part), anywhere that the `nsproxy` token appears, it is replaced by whatever argument is passed.

In this case, the argument `init_nsproxy` is being passed.

Comment: a possible source of confusion in this particular instances is that the linked macro definition does not actually make use of the parameter. The parameter is included for consistency with other similar macros.

Comment: @Rahu:  If the parameter isn't used anywhere, then it is just ignored and it doesn't matter what you pass as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

In this form, you can think of the macro as a function call.
The name of the function is INIT_NSPROXY, and the name of the parameter is nsproxy.
Inside the INIT_NSPROXY macro, nsproxy is replaced by whatever identifier was passed to it.